# xamarin cocosharp - could not get extensions

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

trying to install cocossharp on xamarin for mac.
Visual studio was installed successfully!
when trying to use the extension manager I get these messages:
1.
Could not get information from repository: http://addins.monodevelop.com/Alpha/Mac/7.3.3/main.mrep.

2.
Could not get information from repository: http://addins.monodevelop.com/Beta/Mac/7.3.3/main.mrep.

3.
Could not get information from repository: http://addins.monodevelop.com/Stable/Mac/7.3.3/main.mrep.

Is the address correct? is there another way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: In the Extension manager, in the repository dropdown click add and add this URL: http://addins.monodevelop.com/Beta/Mac/7.2/main.mrep -- basically the same URLs it's using but for v7.2